# How can I resolve this problem in registration PHP form?

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for my English, it's not perfect. I'm doing a registration PHP form, seeing a YouTube tutorial. When I put name, password, email ecc ecc in the registration form, there is a fatal error:

> *Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO)' in C:\pweb\tools\xampp\htdocs\Prova\config.php:7
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\pweb\tools\xampp\htdocs\Prova\config.php(7):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '') #1
>   C:\pweb\tools\xampp\htdocs\Prova\registration.php(2):
>   require_once('C:\pweb\tools\x...') #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\pweb\tools\xampp\htdocs\Prova\config.php on line 7*

How do I resolve this problem? As database, I use PHPMyAdmin. Thanks

Comment: You didn't provide the correct password for the root MySQL user.

Comment: You gave a blank password.

Comment: Probably as a database you are using MySQL as PHPMyAdmin is just database GUI admin tool. you have to put a password in your `config.php` file that corresponds to the `root` user.

Comment: My config.php is this:

<?php   

$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "useraccounts";

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $db_name . '; charset=utf8', $db_user, $db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
?>

I try to put a password but there is also a fatal error